# How to capture screen shot using watir webdriver on a web page that does lazy load of images

Tags: ruby, watir, watir-webdriver

I am using watir webdriver to do some automated testing of web pages. The pages have many images which are lazy loaded when the user scrolls the content into view (uses jquery lazyload plugin)

I am  doing

```
10.times do
    browser.send_keys :space
end
```

To scroll items in view and it loads fine
I also do

```
browser.div(:id => 'footer').wd.location_once_scrolled_into_view
```

which scrolls it to the bottom
and then I do

```
browser.screenshot.save
```

This does not seem to capture any images that are lazy loaded via jquery plugin.

What can I do to capture the entire page

Answer (score 3):

The simplest thing you could do is to scroll to the bottom of the page. Count the images, send `space`, count the images again. If the number of images increased, send `space` again. If the number is the same, you have loaded all images.

Something like this (not tested):

```
old_image_count = 0
new_image_count = browser.imgs
while old_image_count < new_image_count
  old_image_count = browser.imgs
  browser.send_keys :space
  new_image_count = browser.imgs
end
```

Comment: I am sending space keys and that loads the pics, this then works on Chrome and FF, but not on IE 9
On IE 9 it still does only pre loaded pics

Answer (score 0):

Instead of:

```
browser.screenshot.save
```

try:

```
browser.driver.save_screenshot("<path>/photo.jpg")
```

Comment: I think the problem is that the images are not on the page yet.